# Ansible, retrieve ip address for a given network interface via variables

Tags: networking, ansible

I am currently facing an issue with my ansible role, actually my ansible role installed NRPE server on Linux.

In some case, those servers have multiple NIC and need to bind the NRPE server to one particular NIC (dedicated for the monitoring network).

My goal is to retrieve the IP address of a named network card (which is a variable, as from time to time, it could be another NIC) and set this IP to the server_address option in my nrpe.cfg.

After some research, try and error, ansible_fact seems the way to gather those information. I think I will have to register a variable to use with my jinja2 template.

My main issue is how to retrieve IP address from named NIC (enp0s8).

Thanks for your advices.

Regards,

Nikos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your playbook has `gather_facts: yes` or if you run a `setup` task in your playbook there should be a variable like this available.

```
- debug: 
    var: ansible_enp0s8.ipv4.address
```

If you want to see all the possible variables that are normally discovered run a command like this `ansible some-hostname -m setup`.

> I try to build the following variable {{ ansible_{{ nrpe_address_server }}.ipv4.address }} it does not work

You don't use {{}} inside an expression, or to say it differently you can't nest them.

What you probably need is something like this.

```
- debug: 
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_'~nrpe_address_server].ipv4.address
```

Using the [] syntax allows you access specific variable using dynamic data.  The `~` is concatenates strings.

Comment: I understand your answer, however, the network interface could change from server to server. I try to build the following variable `{{ ansible_{{ nrpe_address_server }}.ipv4.address }}` it does not work

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I wanted, thank you for this info. I validate your answer

Comment: finally an answer i needed :D 
How can I use this in set_fact since it seems wrong there:
```"primary_ip": "vars['ansible_'~primary_network_interface].ipv4.address"```

Comment: @mirkobrankovic the 'vars' isn't a good idea anymore, I have been told it is deprecated instead use hostvars.  In your set_fact you might want something like `primary_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][primary_network_interface].ipv4.address }}"`.

Comment: @Nikos, You can't stack moustaches. See [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)